# Why is the Anomalous magnetic dipole moment defined as half the extra contribution to the $g$-factor?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment, dipole-moment

Was there a reason Julian Schwinger or Richard Feynman officially defined the [anomalous magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment) as half of the extra $g$-factor?

$$ a = \frac{g-2}{2} $$

(equation is from the Wikipedia article linked above)

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice explanation of the calculation in [these notes on the Fermilab web site](https://indico.fnal.gov/event/7309/contributions/101335/attachments/66130/79359/notes-3.pdf). The full calculation is a bit long to reproduce here, but the key point is equation 31 on page 6. This shows that the $g$-factor can be written as:

$$ g = 2(F_1(0) + F_2(0)) $$

where $F_1(0)$ turns out to be equal to unity and $F_2(0)$ is calculated from the Feynman diagrams beyond tree level. So the equation is defining the anomalous magnetic moment as $a = F_2(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Such covention for anomalous magnetic moment comes from higher-order calculation of QED.

Electron vertex function can be expanded with two form factor terms.

$$\Gamma^{\mu}(p',p) = \gamma^{\mu} F_1(q^2) + \frac{i \sigma^{\mu\nu} q_{\nu}}{2m} F_2(q^2)$$

Amplitude for electron scattering with static vector potential contains magnetic field, and we can find potential term with Born approximation.

$$ \mathcal{M} \sim - \frac{e}{2m} ( F_1(0)+ F_2(0)) B(q)$$
$$ V \sim  - \frac{e}{2m} ( F_1(0)+ F_2(0)) B(x)$$

We can interpret that term in front of $B$ is magnetic moment. $F_1(0)=1$ (for electric charge), so:

$$ g = 2( 1+ F_2(0)) $$